# How do you find the exact meaning of a word using java?

Tags: java, dictionary

Recently, I was working on a project which required meanings of some words. Is there any API in java which I can use to get the meaning of a word? 
In Python, there used to be a module called PyDictionary:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dict = PyDictionary()
print(dict.meaning("boat"))
```

Can something similar be done in order to find the meaning of a word using Java?

Comment: You could check the source code of that module. Apart from `antigravity` Python doesn't do anything you can't do in other languages as well.

Comment: Just like in Python, you will have to find a library that does this. Or find REST API that doesn't care what programming language you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no restriction or constraints, you can go for dictionary API as provided by many companies. It is a rest call which can be used by any language whether it is python or java. I provide below some links for this. Some apis are free and some are not.

https://www.wordsapi.com/

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/api/pricing,59,HCA.html

There is also a github project for dictionary, you may be interested to check.
https://github.com/shibme/diction

There is also an open source library for word dictionary hosted in sourceforge.net.
http://extjwnl.sourceforge.net/